# Why is filter() returning an error in my React reduxjs/toolkit slice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using reduxjs/toolkit and have an `initialState` object that contains the `globalPropertyList` and a `filterResult` properties. In my reducers I have a `deleteProperty` reducer that filters the `globalPropertyList` by id if `action.payload.id` is not equal to the `property.id`. The specific error I am receiving is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` inside of my Manage.js component (line 23). When I comment out the following inside of my `deleteProperty` reducer I do not receive an error:

```
// commenting the below code out will show the console.log() without an error

// return state.globalPropertyList.filter(
//      (property) => property.id !== action.payload.id
// );
```

This deleteProperty reducer was working before I extracted the initialState property and assigned it an object containing the `globalPropertyList` and the `filterResult`.

I know the reducer is successfully firing because I have added a `console.log` to make sure that the payload id is being successfully passed.

I have been trying to troubleshoot for a while and have not made much progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**propertiesSlice.js**

```
// this slice is in charge of controlling and updating the property portfolio state
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import data from "../data/data";

const initialState = {
    globalPropertyList: data,
    filterResult: [],
};

// the 'createSlice()' function will return some information and assign it to the 'propertiesSlice' variable
const propertiesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "properties",
    initialState,
    // the 'reducer' responds to the action and it takes the 'initialState' and creates a new state based on the action 'payload'
    reducers: {
        // the 'state' is the 'initialState' of the slice => the content will be whatever is in the 'initialState' property
        // the 'action' contains the 'type' and the 'payload' - these come from the component
        addProperty: (state, action) => {
           console.log("added property");

            const newProperty = action.payload;
            state.globalPropertyList.push(newProperty);
        },
        deleteProperty: (state, action) => {
            console.log("deleted property");

            return state.globalPropertyList.filter(
                (property) => property.id !== action.payload.id
            );
        }
    },
});

// exporting the reducer 'addProperty' so the components can dispatch the available reducer actions
export const {
    addProperty,
    deleteProperty,
} = propertiesSlice.actions;

// exporting the reducer so it can be added to the 'store.js'
export default propertiesSlice.reducer;
```

**Manage.js - Component**

```
import React from "react";
import Sidebar from "../../components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import PropertyCardList from "../../components/PropertyCardList/PropertyCardList";

import { Container, Row, Col, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import styles from "./Manage.module.css";

function Manage() {
    // the global 'state' is passed in by the redux 'store' => it will pick out all of the 'properties' from the state
    // the variable 'properties' will contain the current global state
    const properties = useSelector(
        (state) => state.properties.globalPropertyList
    );

    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col md={4}>
                    <Sidebar />
                </Col>
                <Col
                    id={
                        properties.length === 0
                            ? styles.alertWrapper
                            : styles.tilesWrapper
                    }
                    md={8}
                >
                    {properties.length === 0 ? (
                        <Alert
                            className="mx-auto"
                            style={{ width: "50%" }}
                            variant="info"
                        >
                            <Alert.Heading>Getting Started</Alert.Heading>
                            <hr />
                            You can start adding your real estate properties by
                        using the form on the left. Your properties will
                        appear here as you add them.
                        </Alert>
                    ) : (
                        <PropertyCardList />
                    )}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Manage;
```

Comment: Something about the return, try without and say me

Comment: @LutherW the return is needed otherwise the state does not get updated. When you remove the return the console.log is displayed but nothing else happens or gets updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```js
return state.globalPropertyList.filter(...)
```

your state which was `{globalPropertyList: [some array], ...}` becomes simply `[some filtered array]`.

You want to keep the same structure, for instance you can do instead:

```js
state.globalPropertyList = state.globalPropertyList.filter(...)
```

Comment: I've tried something similar. This is the error I get when I assign the filter to the state.globalPropertyList.

Uncaught Error: [Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft.

Comment: As the error message says, if you modify the draft (state), you should not return it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That fixed it. I think I understand. I don't need to return anything because I am directly modifying the initial state (globalPropertyList). React will update the list accordingly across the application.

Comment: Yes, either you modify the initial state and do not return anything, or you return a new state without modifying the initial one, but you cannot do both otherwise Immer/Redux Toolkit doesn’t know what you meant to do.